# Is there something wrong with my RewriteRule? Backreference seems to be behaving weird

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to do a rewriteRule for my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/LoginUser(.*)$ src/core/index.php?url=$1 [L]
```

I'm trying to capture everything that is after LoginUser, hence the group (.*)
and use it in $1. I just want to exclude "/LoginUser" from the query string

Currently:

```
Input: http://foobar.com/LoginUser/Account/cat
Output: http://foobar.com/src/core/index.php?url=/LoginUser/Account/cat
```

But i was expecting:

```
Output: http://foobar.com/src/core/index.php?url=/Account/cat
```

What is wrong with my regex? There must be something wrong with it, been banging my head against the wall, still no answer. If anyone could give me in the right direction, i would be deeply grateful.

Comment: If you actually have this in a .htaccess, then your pattern does not match at all - in that context, the leading slash has _always_ been stripped off of the URL path the rule tests against at this point.

Comment: Ahh.. thanks... problem solved.... thank you CBroe

Answer (score 1):

1. There shouldn't be `/` at the beginning of the rule so the rule you want is:

```
     RewriteRule ^LoginUser(.*)$ src/core/index.php?url=$1 [L]
```

2. The issue with this rule it will also convert:

```
     Input: http://foobar.com/LoginUserToTest/Account/cat
     Output: http://foobar.com/src/core/index.php?url=ToTest/Account/cat
```

To avoid this, the rule you need is:

```
     RewriteRule ^LoginUser/(.*)$ src/core/index.php?url=/$1 [L]
```